# get array value of dynamically created inputs by jquery

Tags: php, jquery

this is a simple code

```
<?php for($i=0; $i<5; $i++){ ?>
    <input type="text" id="modify_album_title_input" name="modify_album_title_input[]" value="" required=""/>
<?php } ?>
```

I can easily get the value by php in a form of array.
But how to get the value by jquery?
I have already used this...

```
alert($("input[name='modify_album_title_input']").val());
```

result is 'undefined'
and this...

```
var input_array= $("input[name='modify_album_title_input[]']").val();
alert(input_array);
```

result only the first of the input, not an array. Any solution guys? thanks in advance...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `.map()`

```
var input_array= $("input[name='modify_album_title_input[]']").map(function() {
    return this.value;
}).get();
```

It only returns the first value in your code since that selector grabs a collection of elements, and simply trying `.val()` grabs the first one. `map()` will generate a nice array of values from the specified selector.

Also, you have repeating ID's, stop that! ID's **must** be unique.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
var arr = new Array();
$("input[name^='modify_album_title_input']").each(function(index){
    arr.push($(this).val());
});
```

Answer (score 1):

A couple things I'm noticing...

1. Your `id` should be unique. In your example you have inputs with the same ID.
2. The `name` attribute is deprecated in HTML5, it should be the same as ID.

Here what I would do: Change to classes.

```
<?php for($i=0; $i<5; $i++){ ?>
    <input type="text" class="modify_album_title_input" value="" required=""/>
<?php } ?>
```

Then you'll be able to get your array like this:

```
var myArray = $('.modify_album_title_input');
```